# How to request the data from database using HTTP get method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, asp.net-core

what is the correct way to request the data from the database using the `[HttpGet]` method? What I want to achieve is I want to have an URL like `https://localhost:44335/Test/date=18-09-2020` when I retrieve the data.  I am trying to request the data from the database using the get method in HTML then pass the data through the controller. I used `Request.QueryString` to request the value that the user entered in HTML form but it does not work well for me. Here is the error that I encounter right now.

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
MySqlException: Parameter '?date' must be defined.
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Statement.SerializeParameter(MySqlParameterCollection parameters, MySqlPacket packet, string parmName, int parameterIndex)

MySqlException: Fatal error encountered during command execution.
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
```

Here my code:

Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using MIMOS.Models;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;

namespace MIMOS.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
        public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }
        public IConfigurationRoot GetConnection()

        {

            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).AddJsonFile("appSettings.json").Build();

            return builder;

        }
        /*public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }*/

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
           
            return View();

        }
        //[HttpGet("{date}")]
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("Test")]
        [Route("Test/{date}")]
        public IActionResult Test(string date)
        {
            Dropdownlist multi_Dropdownlist = new Dropdownlist
            {
                analyticlist = GetAnalytic(),
                testlist = GetSearch()

            };
            return View(multi_Dropdownlist);

            //return View("Index");
        }

        public List<test> GetSearch()

        {

            var connection = GetConnection().GetSection("ConnectionStrings").GetSection("DefaultConnection").Value;

            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connection);
            string sqlQuery = "Select date from statistic where date = " + Request.QueryString["date"].ToString() + ";" ;
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlQuery, con);

            con.Open();

            var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            List<test> list = new List<test>();

            if (reader.HasRows)

            {

                while (reader.Read())

                {
                    list.Add(new test()

                    {

                        date = reader["date"].ToString()

                    });

                }

            }

            con.Close();

            return list;

        }

        public List<Analytic_list> GetAnalytic()

        {

            var connection = GetConnection().GetSection("ConnectionStrings").GetSection("DefaultConnection").Value;

            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connection);

            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Select distinct analytic_id from statistics;", con);

            con.Open();

            var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            List<Analytic_list> list = new List<Analytic_list>();

            if (reader.HasRows)

            {

                while (reader.Read())

                {
                    list.Add(new Analytic_list()

                    {
                        analytic_id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["analytic_id"])

                    });

                }

            }

            con.Close();

            return list;

        }


        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }
    }
}
```

CSHTML

```
<form class="form-inline" action=Home/Test method="get">
   <div class="form-group">
        <label for="date">Date:</label>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="date" name="date">
   </div> &nbsp;&nbsp;
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="search"><i class='fas fa-search' style='color:black'></i></button><br><br>
</form>
```

Comment: This feel too broad for SO and somehow showing worst possible practices on executing SQL queries. You may want to read on "SQL injection" and then [edit] question to narrow it down. Additionally you may want to brush up your knowledge on "C# call methods with parameters"..

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you can get date in your Test method, After testinng, it seems you should remove the Route attribute on it, then I think you can just pass the date to `GetSearch()` method.

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Test(string date)
{
    Dropdownlist multi_Dropdownlist = new Dropdownlist
    {
        analyticlist = GetAnalytic(),
        testlist = GetSearch(date)
    };

    return View(multi_Dropdownlist);
}
```

GetSearch:

```
public List<test> GetSearch(string date)
{
    var connection = GetConnection().GetSection("ConnectionStrings").GetSection("DefaultConnection").Value;
    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connection);
    string sqlQuery = "Select date from statistic where date = " + date + ";" ;

    //...
}
```